Let $(6x^2-2023x+2)^{10}=\sum_{r=0}^{20}a_rx^r.$ Choose the correct options(s) from the following:
The following question is taken from JEE practice set.
Question:
Let $(6x^2-2023x+2)^{10}=\sum_{r=0}^{20}a_rx^r.$ Choose the correct options(s) from the following:
A) $\frac{a_{12}a_9+a_{11}a_8}{a_8a_9}=12$
B) $a_{19}=-6^9\cdot20230$
C) $\lambda=-\sum_{r=1}^{10}a_{2r-1}$ is divisible by $16$
D) $\frac{a_1}{a_0}=-10115$
My Attempt:
$a_rx^r=\frac{10!}{r_1!r_2!r_3!}(6x^2)^{r_1}(-2023x)^{r_2}(2)^{r_3}$
where, $r_1+r_2+r_3=10$
For, $a_0$, $r_1=0 r_2=0, r_3=10$
For $a_1$, $r_1=0, r_2=1, r_3=9$
Therefore, option D,
$\frac{a_1}{a_0}=10\cdot\frac{(-2023)(2^9)}{2^{10}}=-10115$
Option B
For $a_{19}, r_1=9, r_2=1, r_3=0$
So, $a_{19}=10\cdot6^9(-2023)=-6^9\cdot20230$
Option A can be written as $\frac{a_{12}}{a_8}+\frac{a_{11}}{a_9}$
For $a_{12}, (r_1,r_2,r_3)=(6,0,4),(5,2,3),(4,4,2),(3,6,1),(2,8,0)$
For $a_8$, it's same but in reverse order i.e. $(r_3,r_2,r_1)$
But don't know what to do with it.
Same with option C, not able to develop any pattern.

See if you can prove $\frac{a_{12}}{a_8} = 9$ and $\frac{a_{11}}{a_9} = 3$, and then move forward from there.

@Amogh any hint regarding how to prove that?

See that $(r_1, r_2, r_3)$ (for $a_{12}$) and $(r'_1, r'_2, r'_3)$ (for $a_{8}$) are related as $r_1-r'_1=2$, $r_2=r'_2$, and $r'_3-r_3=2$.
The ratio $\frac{a_{12}}{a_8} = \frac{6^2}{2^2} = 9$, similarly $\frac{a_{11}}{a_9} = 3$, hence option (A) is also correct.

Wouldn't that happen if we take (6,0,4) for a_12 and (4,0,6) for a_8? What if we take (6,0,4) for a_12 and (3,2,5) for a_8? In any case, we have to take all the cases together. Because only summing them up would give a particular coefficient, not the individual cases.

When you sum the cases, each term in the numerator would be $9$ times greater than a corresponding term in the denominator, making the overall ratio equal to $9$.

Without considering binomial coefficients, I am getting $$\frac{a_{12}}{a_8}=\frac{6^62^4+6^5(2023)^22^3+...}{6^42^6+6^3(2023)^22^5+...}$$I wonder how to tackle $2023$ factors. Plus there will be binomial coefficients as well.

$6^6 2^4=9(6^4 2^6)$ and so on for each term in the numerator. Hence the ratio equals $9$. $2023$ factors cancel out.

Yes, that makes sense. Thanks. +1. Mind adding something about option C as well so that I could accept your answer?

Here's a hint: For each term in the summation $r_2$ must be odd, and if $r_1 + r_3 \ge 4$ then the term is divisible by $16$. So you just have to check for cases where $r_1 + r_3 < 4$ and $r_2$ is odd. These cases are $(0,9,1), (1,9,0), (0,7,3), (3,7,0), (1,7,2), (2,7,1)$.

Much easier for C: Express that in terms of $f(1), f(-1)$

@CalvinLin, using your hint, I am getting, $\lambda=\frac12((2031)^{10}-(2015)^{10})$. Mind suggesting what to do next? I tried writing each in terms of $4096$ but couldn't conclude.

Well, clearly 2031 - 2015 = 16 is a factor, so we're close! However, we have a pesky 1/2 coefficient, so we will need to look at the other factor. Is it odd or even?
